# Vokera Boiler Emptying Pressure Automatically Emptying When Turned Off

Tags: boiler, venting

So I've bought a new home, and it's a got a Vokera Easy Heat Plus boiler. It works great, and heats up the home cheaply and efficiently. When the boiler is on, the central heating holds water pressure steadily, so there's no leak in the central heating systems or radiators.

The problem is however that when i turn the boiler off because i don't need the central heating system on, after a few hours the boiler just vents the central heating pressure down to 0 bar. But this only happens when i turn the boiler off for a few hours.

And it means that next time i use the boiler i have to repressurize it. It's a little bit inconvenient.

Obviously i don't want to keep the boiler on 24/7 because i don't need it that warm in here, is there a way to stop it venting when the boiler is turned off ? Does anyone have any experience of this happening?